# React: Input Field Loses Focus When Typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How do I prevent my input field from losing focus when typing?

Every time I type in one of my input fields, the field loses focus. Researching the issue, I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064571/react-text-input-loses-focus-when-i-type-a-letter) which talks about how the issue is one component is inside another component.

The reason I'm nesting components is because I'm creating input fields through mapping. I'd like the user to be able to input a value and then have another value computed on that same row. If I don't nest the value, then the same state value is used on all the mapped inputs which causes the same value to be typed into every input on the page.

I'm trying to have an individual input field state for each value. However, doing so now causes the issue where typing into a input field causes that field to lose focus.

**ProjectiveAnalytics.js:**

```
export default function ProjectiveAnalytics({
  predictiveData,
  completionPercentage,
}) {
  return (
    <>
      {predictiveData &&
        predictiveData.map((response) => {
          return (
            <>
              <div key={uuidv4()}>
                <ProjectiveAnalyticsRow
                  response={response}
                  completionPercentage={completionPercentage}
                />
              </div>
            </>
          );
        })}
    </>
  );
}
```

**ProjectiveAnalyticsRow.js:**

```
export default function ProjectiveAnalyticsRow({
  response,
  completionPercentage,
}) {
  const [updateAdSpend, setUpdateAdSpend] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setUpdateAdSpend(event);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className={analyticStyles.resultsColumnDescription} key={uuidv4()}>
        <div>{response.response}</div>
        <div>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Input Ad Spend"
            value={updateAdSpend}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>${(response.sum / (completionPercentage / 100)).toFixed(2)}</div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I think the root cause might be the key on the div. Try to initialise it in a didMount useEffect or something. That way it won't change on each render.

Comment: @HarshilLaheri That fixed it! I can't believe how much time I spent on this... Thank you! If you post this as an answer I'll mark it as solved.

Comment: Alright, rephrasing and posting as answer

Comment: Hi @InquisitiveTom, can you post what your code looked like after the useEffect solution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause is the key on the divs. You can initialise it in a didMount useEffect or something. That way it won't change on each render.